# How to declare View class method definition in an Expo native view module

Tags: react-native, expo

I created an Expo native module like below. I can declare properties of the view. But I have not figured out how to declare class member method yet, like play/pause method of the player view. I am not sure if it's just impossible in Expo. Many thanks

```
    View(VideoPlayerView.self) {
      
      Prop("speed") { (view: VideoPlayerView, speed: Double) in
        view.setSpeed( speed )
      }
```

I searched the source code of Expo

https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/753557f6db11f4ecd1ab25545f2768b0fd863cf7/ios/versioned/sdk47/ExpoModulesCore/ios/Swift/Views/ViewDefinition.swift

and it seems it only support LifeCycleMethod, not generic method. If so, just want to get a confirmation to avoid waste of time